# Trying to force hotspot to use 5GHz band, but uses 2.4GHZ no matter what

Tags: networking, network-manager, nmcli

I am creating an experiment where I am using a bluetooth analyzer. I am creating a wi-fi hotspot that must use the 5GHz band so that it doesn't interfere with bluetooth.

I have edited the Hotspot.nmconnection file to force 5GHz:

```
[connection]
id=Hotspot
uuid=d37d72ae-0731-4bbd-8e4d-ec1b99f4df72
type=wifi
autoconnect=false
interface-name=wlx9418655b6ec2
timestamp=1706128923

[wifi]
band=a
mode=ap
ssid=hw-ble-station

[wifi-security]
group=ccmp;
key-mgmt=sae
pairwise=ccmp;
proto=rsn;
psk=******

[ipv4]
method=shared

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
method=auto

[proxy]
```

The hotspot turns on and can hit the internet, but my spectrum analyzer shows that it is broadcasting in the 2.4GHz range.

On Ubuntu 22.04.[

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbioV.png)

I've tried the following, since modifying nmconnections didn't work:

```
hardwaresyseng@hw-ble-station:~$ nmcli con mod Hotspot wifi.band a
Error: Failed to modify connection 'Hotspot': Insufficient privileges
hardwaresyseng@hw-ble-station:~$ sudo nmcli con mod Hotspot wifi.band a
hardwaresyseng@hw-ble-station:~$ sudo nmcli connection up Hotspot
Error: Connection activation failed: 802.1X supplicant took too long to authenticate
Hint: use 'journalctl -xe NM_CONNECTION=d37d72ae-0731-4bbd-8e4d-ec1b99f4df72 + NM_DEVICE=wlx9418655b6ec2' to get more details.
hardwaresyseng@hw-ble-station:~$ journalctl -xe NM_CONNECTION=d37d72ae-0731-4bbd-8e4d-ec1b99f4df72 + NM_DEVICE=wlx9418655b6ec2
```

The output of iw phy is too large to include as it goes over the 30k character limit, so I cannot include it as requested.

Here is the tail of `journalctl -u wpa_supplicant.service -b -0`:

```
hardwaresyseng@hw-ble-station:~$ tail journal.txt 
Feb 12 17:01:11 hw-ble-station wpa_supplicant[658]: wlx9418655b6ec2: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Feb 12 17:01:11 hw-ble-station wpa_supplicant[658]: Note: nl80211 driver interface is not designed to be used with ap_scan=2; this can result in connection failures
Feb 12 17:01:11 hw-ble-station wpa_supplicant[658]: wlx9418655b6ec2: Failed to start AP functionality
Feb 12 17:01:36 hw-ble-station wpa_supplicant[658]: wlx9418655b6ec2: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Feb 12 17:01:39 hw-ble-station wpa_supplicant[658]: Note: nl80211 driver interface is not designed to be used with ap_scan=2; this can result in connection failures
Feb 12 17:01:39 hw-ble-station wpa_supplicant[658]: wlx9418655b6ec2: Failed to start AP functionality
Feb 12 17:02:05 hw-ble-station wpa_supplicant[658]: wlx9418655b6ec2: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Feb 12 17:02:08 hw-ble-station wpa_supplicant[658]: Note: nl80211 driver interface is not designed to be used with ap_scan=2; this can result in connection failures
Feb 12 17:02:08 hw-ble-station wpa_supplicant[658]: wlx9418655b6ec2: Failed to start AP functionality
Feb 12 17:02:34 hw-ble-station wpa_supplicant[658]: wlx9418655b6ec2: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
```

Here is the tail of `iw phy`:

```
hardwaresyseng@hw-ble-station:~$ tail -200 iw_phy.txt 
            TX STBC
            RX STBC 1-stream
            Max AMSDU length: 7935 bytes
            DSSS/CCK HT40
        Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
        Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 4 usec (0x05)
        HT Max RX data rate: 300 Mbps
        HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-15
        VHT Capabilities (0x039071f6):
            Max MPDU length: 11454
            Supported Channel Width: 160 MHz
            RX LDPC
            short GI (80 MHz)
            short GI (160/80+80 MHz)
            TX STBC
            SU Beamformee
            MU Beamformee
        VHT RX MCS set:
            1 streams: MCS 0-9
            2 streams: MCS 0-9
            3 streams: not supported
            4 streams: not supported
            5 streams: not supported
            6 streams: not supported
            7 streams: not supported
            8 streams: not supported
        VHT RX highest supported: 0 Mbps
        VHT TX MCS set:
            1 streams: MCS 0-9
            2 streams: MCS 0-9
            3 streams: not supported
            4 streams: not supported
            5 streams: not supported
            6 streams: not supported
            7 streams: not supported
            8 streams: not supported
        VHT TX highest supported: 0 Mbps
        Bitrates (non-HT):
            * 6.0 Mbps
            * 9.0 Mbps
            * 12.0 Mbps
            * 18.0 Mbps
            * 24.0 Mbps
            * 36.0 Mbps
            * 48.0 Mbps
            * 54.0 Mbps
        Frequencies:
            * 5180 MHz [36] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5200 MHz [40] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5220 MHz [44] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5240 MHz [48] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5260 MHz [52] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5280 MHz [56] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5300 MHz [60] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5320 MHz [64] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5340 MHz [68] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5360 MHz [72] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5380 MHz [76] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5400 MHz [80] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5420 MHz [84] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5440 MHz [88] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5460 MHz [92] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5480 MHz [96] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5500 MHz [100] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5520 MHz [104] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5540 MHz [108] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5560 MHz [112] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5580 MHz [116] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5600 MHz [120] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5620 MHz [124] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5640 MHz [128] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5660 MHz [132] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5680 MHz [136] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5700 MHz [140] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5720 MHz [144] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5745 MHz [149] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5765 MHz [153] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5785 MHz [157] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5805 MHz [161] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5825 MHz [165] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5845 MHz [169] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5865 MHz [173] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5885 MHz [177] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5905 MHz [181] (22.0 dBm)
    Supported commands:
         * new_interface
         * set_interface
         * new_key
         * start_ap
         * new_station
         * new_mpath
         * set_mesh_config
         * set_bss
         * authenticate
         * associate
         * deauthenticate
         * disassociate
         * join_ibss
         * join_mesh
         * remain_on_channel
         * set_tx_bitrate_mask
         * frame
         * frame_wait_cancel
         * set_wiphy_netns
         * set_channel
         * tdls_mgmt
         * tdls_oper
         * start_sched_scan
         * probe_client
         * set_noack_map
         * register_beacons
         * start_p2p_device
         * set_mcast_rate
         * connect
         * disconnect
         * channel_switch
         * set_qos_map
         * add_tx_ts
         * set_multicast_to_unicast
    WoWLAN support:
         * wake up on disconnect
         * wake up on magic packet
         * wake up on pattern match, up to 20 patterns of 16-128 bytes,
           maximum packet offset 0 bytes
         * can do GTK rekeying
         * wake up on GTK rekey failure
         * wake up on EAP identity request
         * wake up on 4-way handshake
         * wake up on rfkill release
         * wake up on network detection, up to 11 match sets
    software interface modes (can always be added):
         * AP/VLAN
         * monitor
    valid interface combinations:
         * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ AP, P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1,
           total <= 3, #channels <= 2
    HT Capability overrides:
         * MCS: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
         * maximum A-MSDU length
         * supported channel width
         * short GI for 40 MHz
         * max A-MPDU length exponent
         * min MPDU start spacing
    Device supports TX status socket option.
    Device supports HT-IBSS.
    Device supports SAE with AUTHENTICATE command
    Device supports low priority scan.
    Device supports scan flush.
    Device supports per-vif TX power setting
    P2P GO supports CT window setting
    P2P GO supports opportunistic powersave setting
    Driver supports full state transitions for AP/GO clients
    Driver supports a userspace MPM
    Driver/device bandwidth changes during BSS lifetime (AP/GO mode)
    Device adds DS IE to probe requests
    Device can update TPC Report IE
    Device supports static SMPS
    Device supports dynamic SMPS
    Device supports WMM-AC admission (TSPECs)
    Device supports configuring vdev MAC-addr on create.
    Device supports randomizing MAC-addr in scans.
    Device supports randomizing MAC-addr in sched scans.
    Device supports randomizing MAC-addr in net-detect scans.
    max # scan plans: 2
    max scan plan interval: 65535
    max scan plan iterations: 254
    Supported TX frame types:
         * IBSS: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * managed: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * AP: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * mesh point: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-client: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-device: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
    Supported RX frame types:
         * IBSS: 0x40 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * managed: 0x40 0xb0 0xd0
         * AP: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * mesh point: 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * P2P-client: 0x40 0xd0
         * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * P2P-device: 0x40 0xd0
    Supported extended features:
        * [ VHT_IBSS ]: VHT-IBSS
        * [ RRM ]: RRM
        * [ MU_MIMO_AIR_SNIFFER ]: MU-MIMO sniffer
        * [ SCAN_START_TIME ]: scan start timestamp
        * [ BSS_PARENT_TSF ]: BSS last beacon/probe TSF
        * [ BEACON_RATE_LEGACY ]: legacy beacon rate setting
        * [ FILS_STA ]: STA FILS (Fast Initial Link Setup)
        * [ CONTROL_PORT_OVER_NL80211 ]: control port over nl80211
        * [ TXQS ]: FQ-CoDel-enabled intermediate TXQs
        * [ SCAN_MIN_PREQ_CONTENT ]: use probe request with only rate IEs in scans
        * [ EXT_KEY_ID ]: Extended Key ID support
        * [ CONTROL_PORT_NO_PREAUTH ]: disable pre-auth over nl80211 control port support
        * [ DEL_IBSS_STA ]: deletion of IBSS station support
        * [ SCAN_FREQ_KHZ ]: scan on kHz frequency support
        * [ CONTROL_PORT_OVER_NL80211_TX_STATUS ]: tx status for nl80211 control port support
```

```
hardwaresyseng@hw-ble-station:~$ sudo iwlist wlx9418655b6ec2  channel
wlx9418655b6ec2  32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 14 : 2.484 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
```

```
Feb 12 17:09:22 hw-ble-station NetworkManager[621]: <warn>  [1707786562.0050] device (wlx9418655b6ec2): Activation: (wifi) Hotspot network creation took too long, failin>
Feb 12 17:09:22 hw-ble-station NetworkManager[621]: <info>  [1707786562.0051] device (wlx9418655b6ec2): state change: config -> failed (reason 'supplicant-timeout', sys->
Feb 12 17:09:22 hw-ble-station NetworkManager[621]: <warn>  [1707786562.0062] device (wlx9418655b6ec2): Activation: failed for connection 'Hotspot'
Feb 12 17:09:22 hw-ble-station NetworkManager[621]: <info>  [1707786562.0069] device (wlx9418655b6ec2): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-st>
Feb 12 17:11:46 hw-ble-station NetworkManager[621]: <info>  [1707786706.3997] device (wlx9418655b6ec2): Activation: starting connection 'Hotspot' (d37d72ae-0731-4bbd-8e4>
Feb 12 17:11:46 hw-ble-station NetworkManager[621]: <info>  [1707786706.3998] device (wlx9418655b6ec2): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-s>
Feb 12 17:11:46 hw-ble-station NetworkManager[621]: <info>  [1707786706.4002] device (wlx9418655b6ec2): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: >
Feb 12 17:11:46 hw-ble-station NetworkManager[621]: <info>  [1707786706.4005] device (wlx9418655b6ec2): Activation: (wifi) access point 'Hotspot' has security, but secre>
Feb 12 17:11:46 hw-ble-station NetworkManager[621]: <info>  [1707786706.4005] device (wlx9418655b6ec2): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state>
Feb 12 17:11:46 hw-ble-station NetworkManager[621]: <info>  [1707786706.4012] device (wlx9418655b6ec2): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-stat>
Feb 12 17:11:46 hw-ble-station NetworkManager[621]: <info>  [1707786706.4018] device (wlx9418655b6ec2): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: >
Feb 12 17:11:46 hw-ble-station NetworkManager[621]: <info>  [1707786706.4019] device (wlx9418655b6ec2): Activation: (wifi) connection 'Hotspot' has security, and secrets>
Feb 12 17:12:12 hw-ble-station NetworkManager[621]: <warn>  [1707786732.0042] device (wlx9418655b6ec2): Activation: (wifi) Hotspot network creation took too long, failin>
Feb 12 17:12:12 hw-ble-station NetworkManager[621]: <info>  [1707786732.0043] device (wlx9418655b6ec2): state change: config -> failed (reason 'supplicant-timeout', sys->
Feb 12 17:12:12 hw-ble-station NetworkManager[621]: <warn>  [1707786732.0053] device (wlx9418655b6ec2): Activation: failed for connection 'Hotspot'
Feb 12 17:12:12 hw-ble-station NetworkManager[621]: <info>  [1707786732.0059] device (wlx9418655b6ec2): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-st>
```

Comment: Are you sure your card *supports* the 5Ghz range?  **Not all wifi cards support 5GHz bands**

Comment: Please [edit] with `iw phy` and `journalctl -u wpa_supplicant.service -b -0` after retrying after rebooting

Comment: I am using the following network adapter: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0B94R78N7/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1 which supports 5GHz. I have tried rebooting.

Comment: I have added what you requested.

Comment: @DanielPaczuskiBak Does it work if you select channel 153?

Answer (score -1):

First double-check Wi-Fi Adapter Support:
Ensure that the Wi-Fi adapter on your device supports the 5GHz band. Not all Wi-Fi adapters support both 2.4GHz and 5GHz bands.

Then monitor Channel and Frequency:
Use command-line tools or graphical network monitoring tools to check the actual frequency and channel on which the hotspot is broadcasting. This can help you confirm if it's on the 5GHz band.

```
sudo iwlist wlxxxxx channel
```

Update NetworkManager:
Ensure that you have the latest version of NetworkManager installed, as updates may include bug fixes and improvements.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have included the requested information in the original post.